# RoR 3.2: Trying to find a user using his name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an User that has the following

id: 1
Name: Vicenzo Naves
email: (empty for now)

The system is trying to find this user using 'Vicenzo Guilherme Naves'

Does anyone have any suggestion on how I can find the user 1 using the fullest name?

The thing is, I can only receive the fullest name as an input, not only first name and last name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex to capture the parts of the name, and simply ignore the middle name.

This will capture each part of the name.

```
([^ ]+)+
```

In use:

```
params[:user] =~ /([^ ]+)+/
User.find_by_name("#{$1} #{$3}")
```

**Note:** This will not work if say, the name has two middle names, etc. If that is a problem then you can modify it to suit your needs. Maybe like so:

```
parts = params[:user].scan(/([^ ]+)+/)
  # parts will equal [["Vicenzo"], ["Guilherme"], ["Naves"]]
User.find_by_name("#{parts.first.first} #{parts.last.last}")
```